# Windows OpenFile Flags

Tags: windows, go

I am trying to write a program that reads a file while allowing other applications to access it. I’ve learned that in Windows you need to pass syscall.FILESHARE_READ/WRITE flags to prevent file locking. However, introducing these flags restricts me from reading the file in the first place, with the error — read ‘file’: Access is denied.
This is my code:

```
os.OpenFile(path, syscall.O_RDONLY | syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ, 0444)
```

Am I using the correct flags? Is this functionality allowed on Windows?

Here's an example Go program
Building with this command - 
    *GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -v -o testRead.exe*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

if len(os.Args) != 2 {
    fmt.Println("Specify file!")
    return
}

path := os.Args[1]
f, err := os.OpenFile(path, syscall.O_RDONLY|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ, 0444)
//f, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Can't open file")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()

reader := bufio.NewReader(f)
line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(line)


// Keeps the program alive
t1 := time.Now().Local().Add(time.Second * time.Duration(3))
for {
    if time.Now().After(t1) {
        fmt.Println("Still Alive!")
        t1 = time.Now().Local().Add(time.Second * time.Duration(3))
    }
}
}
```

I've observed that reading works fine with os.Open and os.OpenFile(path, syscall.O_RDONLY, 0444).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Obviously, that is not all of your your code. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PeterSO Thanks for the response! I've edited the the question to reflect the problem more.

Answer (score 2):

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

---

If we open the file with

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(path, syscall.O_RDONLY, 0444)
```

your program runs with no errors.

On Windows, the program uses [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) with

```
DesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ
ShareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
```

---

For some unknown reason, you are using arbitrary `os.OpenFile` `flag` bit smashing on Windows.

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(path, syscall.O_RDONLY|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE|syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ, 0444)
```

where

```
const (
    O_RDONLY   = 0x00000
    O_WRONLY   = 0x00001
    O_RDWR     = 0x00002

    FILE_SHARE_READ     = 0x00000001
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE    = 0x00000002
)
```

Smashing the `os.OpenFile` `flag` mode bits with unrelated file share bits, you have

```
flag = syscall.O_RDONLY|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE|syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ
```

or

```
flag = O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY|O_RDWR
```

The results are undefined.

On Windows, an error is reported: `read test.file: Access is denied.`.

On Linux, an error is detected: `read test.file: bad file descriptor`.